# MCU Basic Basics

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, atmel, 8051

A complete novice is here seeking some help regarding MCU. The thing is that I want to develop a project which will help foster my learning of MCU but currently I am at Level (minus) 10.  I have many questions regarding MCU becaue of having little to no experience with those. Since I am inclined towards 8051 variants, my questions will be around that itself. I'll list the questions in pointer form here.

1. What is the main point of difference between a development board/lit or prototyping board? Can I program/burn an MCU if I have one of these or do I need a separate piece of hardware called programmer to put the hex code onto the MCU?
2. What is the difference between the programming of AT89c2051 and ATs52? Which one of the two can I program using the USB port on my laptop without much cost on the additional hardware? I was suggested to use 89v51rd2 because it can be programmed with just MAX232 without the use of any programmer however the additional cost of this MCU prevents me from going for it. I'd rather buy or build a programmer for myself and use 89c2051. But the problem is that I don't know how to program this thing using the USB port on my laptop.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but belongs on electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why are you inclined towards a 35 year old dinosaur MCU with an extremely ineffective architecture? I'm not even sure if any major semiconductor company is still making them. You should look at 32 bit ARM MCUs, if you want to learn about a MCU that is actually used in modern electronics design.

Answer (score 0):

this ticket should get closed since it is not a programming question, primarily opinion based and/or just go read the manual are main reasons.

First off...just go read the manual.  the 8051 is still alive and well but I wouldnt go there as your first mcu.  There are avr based and msp430 based and arm based (and pics, my first but least favorite).  The 8051 and arm based are going to be built by many different chip vendors in many different flavors.  So as far as programming/burning your program into it, it can vary per vendor or chip family per vendor or per chip, basically there is on one answer.  and you will find that some chips have more than one solution.

You wont need a max232.  From usb, that is likely a waste, because you need to get from usb to rs232 levels then the max232 takes you back down to the chips I/O levels (unless your chip is a hybrid and has RS232 levels).  they generally if not always use the normal gpio levels for the uart.  what you are looking for is something ftdi based ft2232 or one of the many variants.  can get cables now with the ftdi part in them or breakout boards  $15 or less (plus stuff to hook it up, pins, jumper wires, whatever).

the arduinos are avr based and are getting cheaper and are massively popular tons of examples and users out there to help.  st has a number of nice cortex-m based boards for $10 to $20 (nucleo, stm32 f0 discovery, f4 discovery).  ti.com/launchpad has a number of boards msp430 and arm based (and their old dsp line if interested) for similar prices.  Sometimes, seems like annually they lower the entry level msp430 board to $4.30.  used to be free shipping but now there is a fairly reasonable shipping cost.

Basically you have to just do your reasearch, the information is all out there, some companies docs are better than others, some products have better online communities or examples or whatever than others.  Then there is the processor type which may or may not matter to you, tools (this day and age the tools should be free, if not move on), libraries if you want to use canned ones or roll your own, etc...It can be overwhelming, perhaps just take the part that you specified, and read more about it, what the programming interface is.  Being atmel their docs are usually pretty good at least for avr and arm based processors but perhaps for their 8051's as well.